# Securing Prometheus scrape endpoints with basic auth or TLS using Prometheus operator

Tags: kubernetes, devops, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-operator

I want to secure different parts of Prometheus, such as the Prometheus /metrics and the node-exporter /metrics, or w.e the endpoint may be. So, if someone were to visit that endpoint, they would need a cert or a username and password.

How do I secure these endpoints using the Prometheus operator and how do I authenticate this using Prometheus?

I've had an initial look on the Prometheus docs but there isn't much info using the Prometheus operator. I've event created a Configmap with the basic*auth and used a volume mount to /etc/prometheus/web*_config/web-config.yml but this seems to break Prometheus.

Any help would be appreciated.

Looking at the docs and github.

Comment: I would suggest you to not expose metrics to the internet it could cause security issues.